# place html elements inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following data:

```css
 .container{
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
}

.sub{
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
<form>
   <input name="id" value="${someValue}" type="hidden"/>
   <label id="error"></label>
   <input type="text" class="sub"  name="amount" value="1" id="amount">
</form>
<button type="submit" name="sudmitButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-default sub" onclick="someFunction()">Submit form</button>
</div>
```

I need to display "amount" and "sudmitButton" elements inline aligned to the left, but now I see these blocks under each other, looks like I have missed something.

Comment: The `<button>` isn't in the `<form>` element. So it will appear underneath the form, which is a `block`

Comment: Use the [*twitter bootstrap*](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) !

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay You are recommending installing a whole framework just to place two elements inline instead of just using CSS?

Comment: @Rob No, good lord no, just look at the Que, it has lines like `class="btn btn-lg btn-default`, `<div class="container">` also the famouse *twitter bootstrap* tag i.e. why

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Instead, he could just make his div wider and solve the problem. He also won't have to learn bootstrap.

Comment: @Rob As a matter of fact, he shouldn't and instead of that just use the predefined classes and let them handle everything instead of writing unnecessary *CSS*

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `float:left` on your form

Answer (score 0):

You set your container to a width of 200px which isn't wide enough to contain both elements. Make the container wider and place the button inside the form element.

Or make the container wider (or remove that constraint altogether) and float the form to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this, include button inside form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Webpage</title>
    <style>
    .container{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;

    }


    .sub{
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;

    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

        <form>
          <input name="id" value="${someValue}" type="hidden"/>
          <label id="error"></label>
          <input type="text" class="sub"  name="amount" value="1" id="amount">
          <button type="submit" name="sudmitButton" class="button_1" onclick="someFunction()" >Submit form  </button>
        </form>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```